# npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.2 install script 'node scripts/install.js

Tags: npm, npm-install

While installing node sass

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

I get follwing error

> npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.2 install script 'node scripts/install.js

Please help?

Comment: I am installing on windows 7